# p-variation of semimartingales

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-analysis, bounded-variation

Does every (particularly continuous) semi-martingale have bounded 2+$\epsilon$-variation for all $\epsilon>0$? Note that I am not asking, whether they have finite quadratic variation - that is clear. I am not sure how to show this and also not sure whether this even holds. If it is not the case, is there an easy counter-example? Any idea is welcome. Thank you very much.

Comment: I put a little more thought into this. Could I proceed in the following way: If $M$ is a continuous local martingale, then $M_t=B_{<M>_t}$, i.e., it is a time changed brownian motion. Now, Brownian motion is $\alpha$-Hölder continuous for all $\alpha<\frac{1}{2}$, therefore of bounded $p$-variation for any $p>2$, which is independent of the parametrization. Therefore, every continuous semimartingale must be of bounded $p$-variation for any $p>2$.